# is it possible to add bucketing on already partitioned table in hive?

Tags: hive, bigdata

Is it possible to create bucketing for a table that already contains partition?

I have a table in hive with more than 100M of records and I want to create a bucket on this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No you can't, you will have to create another table with bucketing enabled:

```
set hive.enforce.bucketing = true;
FROM old_table insert into table new_bucketed_partitioned_table select * ;
```